# Outlier test in discrete survival analysis

Tags: logistic-regression, outliers, survival-analysis, discrete-space

I am trying to figure out how to do a proper test of outliers in a discrete survival analysis (I use a logistic regression). I find a several suggestions for the continuos survival analysis but nothing for the discrete ones.

Suggestions to methods, litterature or likewise are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use dfbetas to do it. I suggest that you read [Therneau's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387987843).